# HTML list item wraps when IE resized

Tags: html, css, menu, resize

I have a horizontal menu bar created using ULs and LIs. The issue I am running into is when on the home page (`default.aspx`) the menu items with long names resize gracefully when IE is resized but once you click on the menu item and you are on that page, the menu goes whacky and the menu items with long names wraps to the next line.

Here is a pic of what I am talking about. How can I not make that wrap and make the UL not resize in the second picture?

[image]

```css
#content-container {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, serif;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

#content-container ul {
  border-bottom: 18px solid #C93;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 -10px;
  ;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 98%;
}

#content-container ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 14.256%;
}

#content-container ul li a {
  border-left: 1px #fff solid;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ddd;
  background-color: #2E4B68;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

#content-container ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #C93;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/dssmenu.css" />
<div id="content-container">
  <ul>
    <li><a id="link1" href="http://mysite/Pages/Training.aspx">Training</a></li>
    <li><a id="link2" href="http://mysite/Pages/Briefings.aspx">Briefings</a></li>
    <li><a id="link3" href="http://mysite/Pages/SecurityDirectives.aspx">Security Directives</a></li>
    <li><a id="link4" href="http://mysite/Pages/DSSInspections.aspx">DSS Inspections</a></li>
    <li><a id="link5" href="http://mysite/Pages/AdverseInformation.aspx">Adverse Information</a></li>
    <li><a id="link6" href="http://mysite/Pages/Travel.aspx">Travel</a></li>
    <li><a id="link7" href="http://mysite/Pages/Resources.aspx">Resources</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider nowrap.

```
#content-container ul li a {
   ....
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Your code helped!!! The menu items dont wrap to the next line but the last menu item still falls down onto the next line as I keep shrinking the IE window. It looks like the container width is shrinking and pushing the list items onto the next line..please help..

Comment: it simply does not fit to a minimum width allocated for browser. Try to do the same for #content-container ul { white-space: nowrap; }